# What does staged Modified mean in SmartGit

Tags: git, smartgit

After pulling the status of some of the files is "Staged Modified".

What does this mean?
If I double click it I can choose to compare between 3 options.

- Head vs Index
- Head vs Working Tree
- Index vs Working Tree

Can you also help me understand the above?
I have looked into it and my understanding is as such:

- Head is where we currently are. So if we checkout a new branch that is the head.
- Working Tree is basically the whole repository on your system.
- Index is the staging

How do I reconcile those notions with the state reported by SmartGit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in "[SmarGit Repositories, Directories and Files](http://www.syntevo.com/doc/display/SG/Repositories%2C+Directories+and+Files)"

> File is modified in the working tree and in the Index in different ways.
>   You may Commit either Index changes or working tree changes.

This is typical of when you add part of a file to the index, but keep part of a file still modified in the working tree.

Illustration from [this article](https://blogs.endjin.com/2015/03/using-git-for-net-development-part-5-staging-some-changes-in-a-file-but-not-others/):

[image: https://blogs.endjin.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/SmartGitstagehunk_thumb.png]

Which gives:

[image: https://blogs.endjin.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/clip_image002_thumb.png]